# glReadPixels doesn't read depth buffer values on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, depth-buffer

I can't seem to read the depth buffer values in OpenGL ES2 on iOS 4.3

```
afDepthPixels = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * iScreenWidth * iScreenHeight);
glReadPixels(0, 0, iScreenWidth, iScreenHeight, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, afDepthPixels);
```

My depth buffer is currently bound in place and operational, however that function reads nothing but 0 values, and it seems to return almost immediately.  If I give it a GL_RGBA, it will take quite a while, and will indeed return results.  Is this functionality just not supported in ES2 on iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As you guess, reading the depth buffer isn't supported in ES 2.x. Per the [glReadPixels man page](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) (direct from Khronos) the only permissible values for 'format' in ES 2 are GL_ALPHA, GL_RGBA and GL_RGB.

From memory, depth textures are supported on recent versions of iOS, so it should be possible to run a pixel shader to convert a depth buffer into something you can read as RGBA if you're otherwise at a dead end.