# OpenGL ES Depth Buffer rendering (iOS simulator VS real device)

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

When rendering the depth buffer with the iOS simulator [Getting the true z value from the depth buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer) , all is fine.
But the rendering on real device gives bad result: the depth is rendered with only few values (there is no fade) like when you display an image into a 256 values color range.

Here is the code for the fbo generation:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &sceneFBO);
glGenTextures(2, textures_scene);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_scene[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, widthResolution, heightResolution, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_scene[1]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, widthResolution, heightResolution, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

//TODO: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT cannot be GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE ?

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, sceneFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_scene[0], 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_scene[1], 0);
```

It seems that the only working value for GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT fbo is GL_UNSIGNED_INT. But it is not enough to render the depth...

*PS: I don't want to display again the scene into a GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 with the z-values in order to have a correct depth (for performance reasons) nor use OpenGL ES3.0 or the new metal (iPhone4s support).*

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally put the z value in the alpha part of the scene (I don't use transparency for this fbo).

```
 color.w=(gl_postion.z-near)/(far-near)
```

A little mcgyver but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

There is no depth buffer support in ES 1 or 2. See the answer to this question : [glReadPixels doesn't read depth buffer values on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563775/glreadpixels-doesnt-read-depth-buffer-values-on-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that it's not possible to use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as *type* parameter together with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` as *internalformat*, only `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` are allowed according to the `GL_OES_depth_texture` extension spec: https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_depth_texture.txt